# How can I set charge levels on ThinkBook

Tags: lenovo, battery, 19.10, charging

I want to set charge levels on my laptop - lenovo thinkbook 14s with Ubuntu 19.10.
I tried installing tcp but it seems as it works only on thinkpads.
I also tried tp smapi same results.

Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install and load the `tp_smapi` kernel module:
Install the `tp-smapi-dkms` module using

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms
```

Now, load the `tp-smapi` module in the kernel using

```
sudo modprobe tp_smapi
```

and set the thresholds to virtual files in `/sys/devices/platform/smapi`

```
echo 35| sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh
echo 75| sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh
```

This setting will make sure that it will stop charging once it reached 75% and only start charging when it drops below 35%.

Comment: In: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tp_smapi it says: *"`tp_smapi` is a set of kernel modules that retrieves information from and conveys commands to the hardware of many ThinkPad laptops before **Ivy Bridge** processors."*